# SQL - How can you filter entries depending on the order I put them in?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

The select I am trying to write orders the data by multiple columns. I want to filter out all entries that are after or before a specific entry in that order.

For example:

`ORDER BY DATE, ID`

gets me:

| ID | DATE | NAME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 13.01.2021 | Alice |
| 3 | 15.01.2021 | Bob |
| 4 | 15.01.2021 | Charlie |
| 6 | 15.01.2021 | Frank |
| 2 | 18.01.2021 | Dave |
| 5 | 18.01.2021 | Eve |

I only want the entries that come after Charlie in this order. (Frank, Dave and Eve)

Is there an easier way to do this than to write a confusing where-clause?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the simplest method uses `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             max(case when name = 'Charlie' then seqnum end) as charlie_seqnum
      from (select t.*, row_number() over (order by date, id) as seqnum
            from t
           ) t
     ) t
where seqnum > charlie_seqnum;
```

An alternative method uses `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.name = 'Charlie' and
                    (t2.date < t.date or
                     t2.date = t.date and t2.id < t.id
                    )
            );
```

Both of these check that `'Charlie'` comes before the row, when ordered by `date` and `id`,

Comment: `row_number()` was pretty much what I was looking for. I hope I can get it to work with my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The `WHERE`, for this, would be:

```sql
...
WHERE [Date] > '20210115'
   OR ([Date] = '20210115' AND [Name] > 'Charlie')
```

I wouldn't say that's particularly confusing.

Comment: A bit like keyset pagination, shame SQL Server doesn't support it

Comment: For my extremely simplified example it works. It gets confusing when you throw some more columns, some weird nested CASE-expressions and collation into the ORDER BY, that I didn't write and barely understand myself.

Comment: This is why you should provide a full [mre] @Dajito . I can only provide an answer based on the information given, I am afraid.

Comment: I mean no offense, but a solution to my example is not the same as a solution to my problem. `WHERE id = 6 OR id = 2 OR id = 5` would also solve the example, but clearly doesn't provide a solution in the context it is given in.

Comment: That wouldn't give rows that are *after* a certain rows (in this case Charlie's on the 15th Jan 2021), just those specific 3; it wouldn't scale. The answer above *does*; as you add more rows those rows (provided that are after charlie) would be returned. That example "solution", in my opinion, isn't comparable.